# How to remove an object from a list of nested objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, angular6

I am using bootstrap treeview.js for creating a tree structure. I have modified this and create 2 btns for add and delete new entries.
after adding a test entry this is my output JSON from where the tree is creating

```
[ 
   { 
      "nodes":[ 

      ],
      "tag_type":"parent",
      "name":"System Summary",
      "id":"XS1025",
      "desc":"KPI\"s for System Summary"
   },
   { 
      "nodes":[ 
         { 
            "nodes":[ 

            ],
            "tag_type":"child",
            "name":"Network",
            "id":"XS1026",
            "desc":"KPI\"s for Network"
         },
         { 
            "nodes":[ 

            ],
            "tag_type":"parent",
            "name":"test1",
            "id":"t1234",
            "desc":"davjwd we "
         }
      ],
      "tag_type":"parent",
      "name":"Monthly CMTS Summary",
      "id":"RS1001",
      "desc":"KPI\"s for Monthly CMTS Summary"
   }
]
```

now For delete, I got the selected ID which user want to delete. But can't remove it from the JSON.
Below is my code which I was trying.

```
deleteNodeFromKpiListData(nodeData: any, nodeId: any): void {
    //nodeData is a single object entry for recursively called function, and nodeId is the selected ID
    for (const [key, result] of Object.entries(nodeData)) {
        if (result['id'] === nodeId) {
            // Here I was trying to delete the objkect from actual JSON
            break;
        } else if (result['nodes'].length > 0) {
            this.deleteNodeFromKpiListData(result['nodes'], nodeId);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried .filter() and .splice() methods for removeing objecrs from an array. But it was not working properly.
Example: If user select to delete "test" then nodeId = "t1234" and the JSON will be

```
[ 
   { 
      "nodes":[ 

      ],
      "tag_type":"parent",
      "name":"System Summary",
      "id":"XS1025",
      "desc":"KPI\"s for System Summary"
   },
   { 
      "nodes":[ 
         { 
            "nodes":[ 

            ],
            "tag_type":"child",
            "name":"Network",
            "id":"XS1026",
            "desc":"KPI\"s for Network"
         }
      ],
      "tag_type":"parent",
      "name":"Monthly CMTS Summary",
      "id":"RS1001",
      "desc":"KPI\"s for Monthly CMTS Summary"
   }
]
```

It was an angular project with typescript. But JavaScript code will be a great help also.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a loop and filter inner nodes and push in a new array!

```js
let myObj = [
    {
        "nodes": [

        ],
        "tag_type": "parent",
        "name": "System Summary",
        "id": "XS1025",
        "desc": "KPI\"s for System Summary"
    },
    {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "nodes": [

                ],
                "tag_type": "child",
                "name": "Network",
                "id": "XS1026",
                "desc": "KPI\"s for Network"
            },
            {
                "nodes": [

                ],
                "tag_type": "parent",
                "name": "test1",
                "id": "t1234",
                "desc": "davjwd we "
            }
        ],
        "tag_type": "parent",
        "name": "Monthly CMTS Summary",
        "id": "RS1001",
        "desc": "KPI\"s for Monthly CMTS Summary"
    }
];


let myObjNew = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {

    let myinner = myObj[i];
    let nodeObj = myObj[i]['nodes'];
    let nodeOnly = nodeObj.filter((item) => !item['id'].includes('t1234'));

    myinner.nodes = nodeOnly;
    myObjNew.push(myinner);


}
console.log(myObjNew)
```

Your looks like somthing

```
deleteNodeFromKpiListData(nodeData: any, nodeId: any): void {
    let myObjNew = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeData.length; i++) {

        let myinner = nodeData[i];
        let nodeObj = nodeData[i]['nodes'];
        let nodeOnly = nodeObj.filter((item) => !item['id'].includes('t1234'));

        myinner.nodes = nodeOnly;
        myObjNew.push(myinner);

    }
    this.nodeData = myObjNew;
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, but can't produce the actual structure. Can You help me with some codes??

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the node element but it's undefined. Remove undefined from the list.

```js
var data = [
   {
      "nodes":[

      ],
      "tag_type":"parent",
      "name":"System Summary",
      "id":"XS1025",
      "desc":"KPI\"s for System Summary"
   },
   {
      "nodes":[
         {
            "nodes":[

            ],
            "tag_type":"child",
            "name":"Network",
            "id":"XS1026",
            "desc":"KPI\"s for Network"
         },
         {
            "nodes":[

            ],
            "tag_type":"parent",
            "name":"test1",
            "id":"t1234",
            "desc":"davjwd we "
         }
      ],
      "tag_type":"parent",
      "name":"Monthly CMTS Summary",
      "id":"RS1001",
      "desc":"KPI\"s for Monthly CMTS Summary"
   }
];
function removeElementById(data_array,node_id){
  for(var a=0;a<data_array.length;a++){
    if(data_array[a]["id"]===(node_id)){
      delete data_array[a];
      var tempData = data_array.filter(function(d){
        return d!=null || d!=undefined;
      })
    }else if(data_array[a]["nodes"].length>0){
      removeElementById(data_array[a]["nodes"],node_id);
    }
  }
}
removeElementById(data,"t1234");
console.log(data);
```